AWS Chime Error : The signaling connection was closed with code 4403 and reason: attendee unavailable
I am using amazon-chime-sdk-component-library-react for creating the meeting manager and everything is working as expected. The code is as follows.
const data = await response.json();
        const { Info } = data;
        const { Meeting, Attendee } = Info;
        const configuration = new MeetingSessionConfiguration(Meeting.Meeting, Attendee.Attendee);
        await meetingManager.join(configuration);
        await meetingManager.start();

But the issue is when the deleteAttendee is called and the user is successfully deleted from the meeting. Then If the user tries to connect again within a few seconds the user joins the meeting and after 5 to 10 seconds. He automatically left the meeting with these console errors.

ChimeSDKReactComponent - failed with status code SignalingBadRequest and error: The signaling connection was closed with code 4403 and reason: attendee unavailable
failed with status code SignalingBadRequest and error: The signaling connection was closed with code 4403 and reason: attendee unavailable


ChimeSDKReactComponent - the session will not be reconnected.

I have called the await meetingManager.leave();. After the attendee successfully deleted from the meeting. The code sample
const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/meeting/delete-attendee`, {
                    method: "DELETE",
                });
if (!response.ok) {
  throw new Error(`HTTP status ${response.status}`);
}
  await meetingManager.leave();

Snapshot of the console:

What's the solution to these issues and why the attendee left the meeting automatically?

There are two reasons why this issue occurred, Which are as follows

Do not delete the attendee before clearing the meetingManager resources like await meetingManager.leave();

Note*: First, clear the meetingManager resources and call await meetingManager.leave();

Secondly clear some resources like from meetingManager.


meetingManager?.audioVideo?.removeVideoTilesByAttendeeId(attendeeId);
meetingManager?.audioVideo?.stop();
meetingManager?.audioVideo?.stopAudioInput();
meetingManager?.audioVideo?.stopContentShare();
meetingManager?.audioVideo?.stopVideoInput();
meetingManager?.audioVideo?.stopLocalVideoTile();
meetingManager?.audioVideo?.unbindAudioElement();

